# Almacenar IP que responde en .txt

Tags: c, ip

Me encuentro devanándome los sesos para lograr programar en C una aplicación que, dado un listado de IP's en .txt separados por distintas líneas, haga ping una a una y muestre cuáles responden con velocidad media. Según me comentan, la fórmula correcta sería redireccionar el mensaje que ofrece la pantalla al llevar a cabo mi comando que hace ping automático a un .txt externo y a partir de ahí releerlo con otro comando y seleccionar las distintas a "media = 0ms" (es decir, las que ofrezcan respuesta a la llamada ping), pero no acabo de entender muy bien cómo formularlo. Agradecería enormemente todo tipo de ayuda.

¿Cómo puedo remarcar las IP's que ofrecen respuesta al ping? 
Intuyo que de alguna manera, con un "`if`... != "recibidos: 0"... 
`else`...", pero no sé muy bien cómo formularlo.

Un saludo y gracias de antemano.

```
    FILE* fp;
    char ch[500], x[225], str[80];

    printf("\n    Escribe la ruta del documento deseado\n\n");
    scanf("%s", x);

    fp = fopen(x, "r");
    //freopen("out.txt", "a", stdout);

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("El archivo no se ha podido encontrar.");
        exit(0);
    }

    while (fgets(ch, 100, fp)) {
        printf("%s", ch);
    }
            rewind(fp);

            while (!feof(fp)) {
                fgets(ch, 100, fp);
                strcpy(str, "ping ");
                strcat(str, ch);
                system(str);
            }
```

Comment: Agrega el codigo que hayas intentado.

Comment: Código agregado. Finalmente, he podido redireccionar la pantalla a un .txt llamado "out.txt", pero estoy encallado. ¿Cómo puedo remarcar las IP's que ofrecen respuesta al ping? Intuyo que de alguna manera, con un "if... != "recibidos: 0"... else...", pero no sé muy bien cómo formularlo. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: A que te refieres con velocidad media?

Comment: Cómo lo adjunta a ms debe referirse a la latencia media obtenida durante el ping

Comment: Editado para mayor claridad. En definitiva, habiendo logrado hacer ping automático a las IP's del .txt seleccionado y almacenando el log o resultado de éstas en un archivo redireccionado .txt alternativo, necesitaría remarcar cuáles de ellas responden favorablemente al ping.

Answer (score -1):

esto lo resolvieron así vía bash:
Fuente : http://www.linuxito.com/gnu-linux/nivel-medio/164-script-para-monitorear-un-enlace

```
#!/bin/bash

# host to ping
#TARGET="www.siteuptime.com"
TARGET="8.8.8.8"

# log file
LOG="/var/log/net-uptime.log"

# ping 3 packets every 2 seconds, wait 3 seconds maximum
PING=$(ping -n -c 3 -i 2 -W 3 $TARGET 2>&1)

if [[ $? != 0 ]]
then
        if [[ $PING =~ "loss" ]]
        then
                # no reply
                ERROR=$(echo "$PING" | grep 'loss')
        else
                # destination unreachable
                ERROR=$PING
        fi
    echo "$(date +%F\ %T) - Failed check - $ERROR" &>> $LOG
fi
```

Comment: La etiqueta de la pregunta es de C. Te invito a leer: [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)